# Laravel Framework not showing errors

Tags: php, laravel

Can anyone explain if there is a way to catch or log errors when the following code is executed?

```
//This has example has no semicolon.  
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
{
    return View::make('profile')
});
```

or

```
//This example has no dollar sign (part of a blade template).
Welcome {{ userName }}
```

I end up with an empty page for these and there have been a few other times this has happened where I can't remember the details.

I have debug set to true in app/config/app.php and I don't get any errors in the log files at app/storage/logs

Is this normal or do I have a problem with my setup?

Thanks

***UPDATE***

Laravel log commands aren't working for me. See the comment in reply to msturdy.

Comment: You really should be seeing thrown errors.. We'd need more detail to troubleshoot.  You can use the `Log` class to write to the log files: http://laravel.com/docs/errors#logging

Comment: Interestingly none of the log commands work for me, they all result in  a 500 error page. I've tried wrapping them in try catch. Here is my route `Route::get('/', function()
{
 try {
     Log::error('Something is really going wrong.');
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  exit();
 }
 return 'hello world';
});` without the try catch I get hello world with it I get 500 error. Any ideas how to debug? I've checked Google and there is nothing obvious there.

Comment: Well.. that's not what I would expect.. Sounds like you have serious problems with the installation.. I would recommend pulling the latest Laravel, and starting from scratch with copies of your `routes.php`. `models` and `views`... copying things one at a time into the new installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this now. I downloaded the latest Laravel and still had identical issues. Eventually I found out that Apache was pointing at a old version of php (5.3.0) that lived on a different drive (no idea how I've done that), anyway I had my command line pointed at the correct version of php, so that's why I've had no issues when installing/updating Laravel.

Small chance anyone would see similar issues as it was a bit of a random situation (my apologies). I now get the prettiest runtime exception page I've ever seen when running the examples :). Thanks msturdy

Comment: hehe, I thought it was something weird :)